# div is displaying over a table

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="ticket_summary" style="height:60px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#666666" align="left"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Summary</strong></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#666666" align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $result["datetime"]; ?></strong></font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["summary"])) ;?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><hr /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I then have another table below:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="showticketupdates"><a onclick="show_ticketupdates()"><h3>Show Ticket Updates</h3></a></div>
        <div id="hideticketupdates" style="display:none;"><a onclick="hide_ticketupdates()"><h3>Hide Ticket Updates</h3></a></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

the `ticket_summary` `<div>` is displaying over the link below. I think it has something to do with the style on the `<div>` - what can i add to stop it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of height, try making it to min-height, so:

```
<div id="ticket_summary" style="min-height:60px;">
```

Therefore it will extend when the length of ticket_summary div exceeds 60px.

Also try putting your second table in a div.

EDIT:
If you want to have a fixed height and just show a scroll bar when it exceeds your desired height, then just keep the height and add an `overflow: scroll;` to your ticker summary div:

```
<div id="ticket_summary" style="height:60px; overflow:scroll;">
```

Also, I noticed that you put an hr at the end of the table. But this will not be displayed if there's an overflow so I suggest that you just move the `<hr />` at the end of the first table.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AmqRJ/

Comment: i dont want it to expand on its own - i want it to be a fixed height and then i will add the overflow as scroll

Comment: @CharlieFord I don't get it. If you already know the answer, why not simply do it? Why post here with a question with incomplete information and then complain that a perfectly valid answer doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: ok if you could tell me where i know the answer that would be great as i dont know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write this:

```
<div id="ticket_summary">
```

in place of:

```
<div id="ticket_summary" style="height:60px;">
```

Then, write this:

```
<td colspan="3"><div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 60px;"><?php echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["summary"])) ;?></div></td>
```

in place of:

```
<td colspan="3"><?php echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["summary"])) ;?></td>
```